# Why does clearing a canvas clear the parent canvas in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

If I do the following for a TPaintBox, I clear the parent control as well as the paint control:

```
canvas.BeginScene;
canvas.Clear(TAlphaColors.Gray);
canvas.EndScene;
```

If I switch to ClearRect, it then works correctly:

```
canvas.BeginScene;
canvas.ClearRect(TRectF.Create(0, 0, width, height), TAlphaColors.Gray);
canvas.EndScene;
```

I'm guessing it's because the paint box is sharing the parents canvas and clear works on that, but clear rect does the right thing. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1):

The paintbox inherits its canvas from the parent control. It simply implements paint methods. If you want something different, put e.g. a panel on and make that the parent of the paintbox.